# How to toggle input fields based on dropdown menu with multiple selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu made by  with multiple selection feature.
I also have some form inputs fields containing some divs, label and input tags.
I want to show a particular form field on selection of that particular item in select menu.

Lets say, I have

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Identity Proofs</label>
        <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select at least one valid Identity Proof"
                            style="width: 100%;" id="idproof">
            <option value="aadhar">Aadhar Card</option>    
            <option value="passport">Indian Passport</option>    
            <option value="voter-ID">Voter ID Card</option>    
            <option value="pan">PAN Card</option>    
            <option value="dl">Driving License</option>    
            <option value="ration">Ration Card</option>    
            <option value="birth">Birth Certificate</option>    
            <option value="scst">Backward classes Certificate</option>    
            <option value="udid">Unique Disability ID (UDID) Card</option>    
            <option value="army">Army License</option>
            <option value="others">Others</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to select multiples values from the above menu.

Then I have 11  or  fields which I want to toggle the visiblity.

When I select "aadhar", the div with id="id1" should be visible.
similarly,
When I select "passport", the div with id="id2" should be visible.
similarly,
When I select both "voter-ID" and "pan", the div with id="id3" and id="id4" should be visible.

I have already tried many if else and else if statements with jQuery's hide() and show() function. Every method works fine for SINGLE SELECTION but not for multiple selections. I am very frustrated by this issue.

Then i tried FOR loop (I dont know js or jQuery much). But still it does not helps. Below is the code

```
$("#idproof").on('change',function(){
    var arrayid = ["id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8","id9","id10","id11"];
    var arrayname = ["aadhar","passport","voter-ID","pan","dl","ration","birth","scst","udid","army","others"];
    var i,j;
    for (j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
if($("#idproof").val()=="arrayname[i]"){
    $("#arrayid[i]").hide();
}
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
if($("#idproof").val()=="arrayname[i]"){
    $("#arrayid[i]").show();
}
    }

});
```

I even tweaked the syntax(thinking it is wrong) but it did not helped. I even tried "display:none" in the divs and then changing it through jQuery but still no hope.

my last attempt was:

```
$("#idproof").on('change',function(){
    $("#id1","#id2","#id3","#id4","#id5","#id6","#id7","#id8","#id9","#id10","#id11").hide()
    if( !($("#idproof").val()=="aadhar")){
    $("#id1").hide()
    }
    else{
            $("#id1").show()
        }
    if( !($("#idproof").val()=="passport")){
    $("#id2").hide()
    }
     else{
            $("#id2").show()
        }
    if( !($("#idproof").val()=="voter-ID")){
    $("#id3").hide()
    }
     else{
            $("#id3").show()
        }
    if( !($("#idproof").val()=="pan")){
    $("#id4").hide()
    }
     else{
            $("#id4").show()
        }
    if( !($("#idproof").val()=="dl")){
    $("#id5").hide()
    }
     else{
            $("#id5").show()
        }
    if( !($("#idproof").val()=="ration")){
    $("#id6").hide()
    }
     else{
            $("#id6").show()
        }
    if( !($("#idproof").val()=="birth")){
    $("#id7").hide()
    }
     else{
            $("#id7").show()
        }
    if( !($("#idproof").val()=="scst")){
    $("#id8").hide()
    }
     else{
            $("#id8").show()
        }
    if( !($("#idproof").val()=="udid")){
    $("#id9").hide()
    }
     else{
            $("#id9").show()
        }
    if( !($("#idproof").val()=="army")){
    $("#id10").hide()
    }
     else{
            $("#id10").show()
        }
    if( !($("#idproof").val()=="others")){
    $("#id11").hide()
    }
     else{
            $("#id11").show()
        }
});
```

The below code works for single selection(but still buggy)

```
$("#idproof").on('change',function(){ $("#id1","#id2","#id3","#id4","#id5","#id6","#id7","#id8","#id9","#id10","#id11").hide() if( !($("#idproof").val()=="aadhar")){ $("#id1").hide() } else{ $("#id1").show() } if( !($("#idproof").val()=="passport")){ $("#id2").hide() } else{ $("#id2").show() } if( !($("#idproof").val()=="voter-ID")){ $("#id3").hide() } else{ $("#id3").show() } if( !($("#idproof").val()=="pan")){ $("#id4").hide() } else{ $("#id4").show() } if( !($("#idproof").val()=="dl")){ $("#id5").hide() } else{ $("#id5").show() } if( !($("#idproof").val()=="ration")){ $("#id6").hide() } else{ $("#id6").show() } if( !($("#idproof").val()=="birth")){ $("#id7").hide() } else{ $("#id7").show() } if( !($("#idproof").val()=="scst")){ $("#id8").hide() } else{ $("#id8").show() } if( !($("#idproof").val()=="udid")){ $("#id9").hide() } else{ $("#id9").show() } if( !($("#idproof").val()=="army")){ $("#id10").hide() } else{ $("#id10").show() } if( !($("#idproof").val()=="others")){ $("#id11").hide() } else{ $("#id11").show() } });
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2u38koq8/1/ This is something relatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below works as you would like. It adds a click event to the options within a select, and then cycles through each option checking if it has been selected. Using an index we can then show or hide the associated `div`.

I've added a really nasty bit of CSS to start all the associated divs as hidden - do not do it this way! Add a class to the divs as this CSS rule is not specific enough to use outside of a demo.

There are more elegant ways of doing this, ideally using an attribute for each option, providing the name for the associated div. For instance, you could reuse the `option` `value` as the `id` of the associated div. This would make the coding simpler.

Let me know if this wasn't what you wanted.

---

Demo

```js
// Add click event to options
$("select option").click( function() {


  // Create index value
  i = 1;
  
  // Cycle through each of the options
  $(this).closest("select").children("option").each( function() {

    // Check if option is selected
    if ( $(this).is(':selected') ) {
    
      // If it is, show associated div
      $("#id" + i).show();
    
    } else {
    
      // If it is not selected, hide associated div
      $("#id" + i).hide();
    
    }
  
    // Increase index
    i = i + 1;
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
[id^='id'] {
  display: none;
}
#idproof {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Identity Proofs</label>
        <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select at least one valid Identity Proof"
                            style="width: 100%;" id="idproof">
            <option value="aadhar">Aadhar Card</option>    
            <option value="passport">Indian Passport</option>    
            <option value="voter-ID">Voter ID Card</option>    
            <option value="pan">PAN Card</option>    
            <option value="dl">Driving License</option>    
            <option value="ration">Ration Card</option>    
            <option value="birth">Birth Certificate</option>    
            <option value="scst">Backward classes Certificate</option>    
            <option value="udid">Unique Disability ID (UDID) Card</option>    
            <option value="army">Army License</option>
            <option value="others">Others</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="id1">Aadhar Card #id1</div>
<div id="id2">Indian Passport #id2</div>
<div id="id3">Voter ID Card #id3</div>
<div id="id4">PAN Card #id4</div>
<div id="id5">Driving License #id5</div>
<div id="id6">Ration Card #id6</div>
<div id="id7">Birth Certificate #id7</div>
<div id="id8">Backward classes Certificate #id8</div>
<div id="id9">Unique Disability ID #id9</div>
<div id="id10">Army License #id10</div>
<div id="id11">Others #id11</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `<select>` is multi-select then this returns an array:

```
$("#idproof").val()
```

So this would never be true:

```
$("#idproof").val() == "aadhar"
```

Instead, just get your array and check if the array contains the value.  Something like:

```
let selectedValues = $("#idproof").val();
if (selectedValues.indexOf('aadhar') > -1) {
    // show your elements
}
if (selectedValues.indexOf('passport') > -1) {
    // show your other elements
}
// etc.
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I tried it but it did not work. I added jquery function to toggle the visiblity of the form inputs. What is the right way?

Comment: @Swagatdash: What specifically did you try and how specifically did it fail?  You can update your question with additional information.